# Как решать задачи требующие циклов в postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

У меня 2 таблицы марки телефонов и сами телефоны с суммами по которым они были проданы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS models (
  id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(15) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phones (
  id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  model_id INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  prise    BIGINT    NOT NULL,
  date     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  user_id  INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (model_id) REFERENCES models (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

Моя задача заключается в том что-бы получить названия телефонов, которые в промежуток времени продались на меньшую сумму чем заданная, и были отсортированы по убыванию.

Я делаю это так:

Получаю все записи в таблице `models`

```
SELECT * FROM models;
```

И потом иду получаю сумму на которую была продана данная модель:

```
SELECT sum(p.prise) FROM phones AS p
WHERE p.model_id = 2
      AND p.date >= '2017-11-02 23:21:31.59098'
      AND p.date <= '2017-12-05 23:21:31.59098';
```

И так для каждой модели, а потом еще отсекаю не нужное, и сортирую уже за пределами `SQL`.

Помогите пожалуйста получить данные либо одним запросом, или хотябы сделать так, чтобы их колличество не росло линейно вместе с колличеством записей в `models`. Мне бы в рамках одного запроса итерироваться по `models` и на каждой итерации получать сумму по модели и записывать результат, но как это сделать в `SQL` не понимаю. Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки. Спасибо.

Comment: А что значит отсекаете не нужное ? вы из своего второго запроса уберите model_id=2, выведите этот самый model_id, сделайте group by до него же и в having напишите что мол sum(prise)<X. ну и можно еще join первой таблицы туда же до кучи, что бы имена были

Comment: @Mike отсекаю в смысле что получаю все результаты а потом уже перекладываю в отдельный List. А что значит ВЫВЕДИТЕ этот самый model_id я вот по идее и должен как то по этому model_id как бы итерироваться но не знаю как.

Comment: не надо никаких циклов, `group by model_id` сделает все за вас, соберет суммы в разрезе model_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  m.name,
  sum(p.price) as cost
from (
    select * from phones
    where date between '2017-11-02 23:21:31.59098' and '2017-12-05 23:21:31.59098'
) as p
inner join models as m
  on p.model_id = m.id
group by m.name
having sum(p.price) < 42000
order by cost desc;
```

Comment: почему-то ругается на `ERROR:  column "p.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` а когда я в `group by m.name` добавил `p.priсe` то появилась проблема что в полученной колонке `name` куча дубликатов и результат получается просто огромным. Может быть можно как то указать что дубликаты не нужны не задавая еще один вопрос? Спасибо большое за ответ...

Comment: @Pavel вам order by нужен же по сумме, а не по отдельным строкам. тут ошибка в запросе, в order by надо писать `sum(p.price)`. И вообще как то сложновато написано. https://pastebin.com/NPkSkHKf

Comment: @Mike можно и без подзапроса, но будет медленнее, если таблица `phones` объёмная. Сортировку исправил, спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Хм, у postgresql такой плохой оптимизатор ... не ожидал. Oracle бы одинаковый план выполнения на оба запроса дал, причем как раз такой как вы ожидаете получить за счет подзапроса

Comment: @Mike я, честно говоря, очень давно не проверял. Может сейчас это и поменялось.